# How setup JMS without Spring, I'm using Google Guice

Tags: java, spring, jms, guice

I'm facing some problems trying to setup JMS without spring boot, before I was using Spring and everything was working fine, but now I won't use it anymore, I'm using Google Guice for some reasons.

I configured that Jms class config to inject the things that it requires

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageType;
import org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.util.backoff.FixedBackOff;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {

    private static final String JMS_TYPE_ID_PROPERTY_NAME = "_type";

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsQueueFactory(
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {

        log.info("JmsConfig.jmsQueueFactory - (TraceTest1)");
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

        // This provides all Spring Boot's defaults to this factory, including message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);

        factory.setErrorHandler(new JmsErrorHandler());
        factory.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());

        //retry indefinitely every 60 seconds
        factory.setBackOff(new FixedBackOff(60000, FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS));

        return factory;
    }

    public static class JmsErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsErrorHandler.class);
        @Override
        public void handleError(Throwable t) {
            log.error("JMS error", t);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        log.info("JmsConfig.jacksonJmsMessageConverter - (TraceTest2)");
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName(JMS_TYPE_ID_PROPERTY_NAME);
        return converter;
    }
}
```

The problems is, now that I'm not using Spring this class and respective beans does not initialize during the application start.

I have another method in another class, kind of a Main that has a "start method", I want to abstract this to call it there without spring but I could not find implementation of it manually using Guice, could you guys help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Jms is a spring techonologie that depend of spring you can use it without spring if you want to initialize it from juice you have to use the spring guice bridge : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-guice

Comment: Thanks for you answer @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec, I think I got, can you clarify me 2 things?
1) Using this bridge I would be able to let the class the way it are and just have to configure some some stuffs?
2) Should I add this as a dependency in my project?

Comment: yes and yes : you will found some exemple inside the git repository and you will need to use the bridge as dependancy to handle spring and and guice cohabitation^^

Comment: I've made some tries but didn't work. I'll read all the examples and see which one fits to me. Thanks!

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec, JMS is not a Spring technology.  It's part of the JEE spec.

Comment: yes but you need spring or EJB to handle it correctly guice didn't provide support for this

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec  You don't need Spring or EJB to handle JMS. You can do it in plain Java. You are misinformed.

Comment: provide a web service without any service handler i dont see the interest

Comment: Couldn't make it works, guys. @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec not sure why but looks like that spring-guice needs a Spring Context and I do not have it, correct if I'm wrong, but looks like the Application still does not execute during it's startup, is there any other suggestion?
I don't have Knowledge in this area, couldn't I do it manually? I have a "Start" method that I could try to put some stuffs, just don't know what